# Creating Fragments dynamically with weight pamameter

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-fragments

I am creating app in which I have to add 3 fragments dynamically each should occupy same space. For this I am using LayoutParams, but its not working, its giving Java.lang.NullPointerException.
Please help me to resolve error.

Fragment class

```
public class HeaderFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable_activity, container, false);
}
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class TimeTableActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.timetable_activity);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeaderFragment firstFragment = new HeaderFragment();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

        firstFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
        BodyFragment secondFragment = new BodyFragment();
        secondFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
        FooterFragment thirdFragment = new FooterFragment();
        thirdFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_layout, firstFragment).commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_layout, secondFragment).commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_layout, thirdFragment).commit();

    }

}
}
```

Main Activty.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id = "@+id/fragment_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat Description

```
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688): Process: com.deiontech.masjidtimetableapp,      PID: 1688
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.deiontech.masjidtimetableapp/com.deiontech.masjidtimetableapp.TimeTableActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):at      android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at  com.deiontech.masjidtimetableapp.TimeTableActivity.onCreate(TimeTableActivity.java:27)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at    android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-02 02:17:58.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1688):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: where is the view with id `R.id.fragment_layout`?. what is line 27 `TimeTableActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity's `onCreate()`, you're creating a new fragment and immediately trying to access its view:

```
    HeaderFragment firstFragment = new HeaderFragment();
    ...
    firstFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

This will not work, because the layout will inflate when the fragment attaches to the activity, which you are doing several lines further down:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_layout, firstFragment).commit();
```

Bear in mind that attaching fragments to an activity is asynchronous, so simply rearranging the statements in `onCreate()` will not resolve the problem. You should instead set the layout parameters in the fragment's `onViewCreated()` (if you simply need to modify the fragment's view) or `onAttach()` (if you need to access the view hierarchy to the parent activity).

I'd like to suggest that you avoid this altogether by instantiating your fragments through the layout. For instance:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment android:name="fully.qualified.path.to.HeaderFragment"
              android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <fragment android:name="fully.qualified.path.to.HeaderFragment"
              android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <fragment android:name="fully.qualified.path.to.HeaderFragment"
              android:id="@+id/third_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but going further I should be able to remove fragment and add another fragment dynamically..Is this is possible if i declare it in xml as you have given

Comment: Yes, your logic around `FragmentManager` looks OK.

Comment: I added code for setting parameters in onViewCreated() of fragment now its working fine :) Thank you So much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.timetable_activity);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeaderFragment firstFragment = new HeaderFragment();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

        firstFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
        BodyFragment secondFragment = new BodyFragment();
        secondFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
        FooterFragment thirdFragment = new FooterFragment();
        thirdFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.first, firstFragment).commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.second, secondFragment).commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.third, thirdFragment).commit();

    }
```